# Delta function in curved space

Tags: differential-geometry, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

In flat space I may write a delta function as

$$\delta^{d} (x-y) = \lim_{t \to 0} (4\pi t)^{-d/2}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}.$$ So, does the curved space analogue look like

$$\delta^{d} (x,y) = \lim_{t \to 0} (4\pi t)^{-d/2}e^{-\frac{\sigma(x ,y)}{4t}}$$ where $\sigma$ is the geodesic distance square between $x, y$ ?

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to represent $\delta$ as a limit of functions, this is true even in the flat space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dirac-delta function $\delta(x,y)$ is defined by the condition that it is localised at a point $y$, and when its product with a test function $f(x)$ is integrated it yields the value of the test function at the point $y$.

Now on a Riemannian manifold, the invariant volume is $\mathrm{d}^dx \sqrt g $ where $g$ is the determinant of the metric. The invariant delta function should thus be

$\delta^{d} (x-y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt g}\lim_{t \to 0} (4\pi t)^{-d/2}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4t}}.$

This probably doesn't answer your question fully, but could be helpful if you need it for computation.

Comment: Through the multiplication with $\frac{1}{\sqrt g}$ you have partially moved to the coordinate system (possibly curvilinear) used, but then you should also change $(x-y)^2$ to use the expression for the distance in that coordinate system.

Comment: @User90041 Shouldn't instead of $(x-y)^2$ one should have $\sigma$ that is the geodesic distance ?

Comment: @user44690 If you make that replacement, the first statement of my answer won't hold. Hence the resulting function wouldn't be a delta function in that sense.